# How to get UniquePtr<EnumMember> on the Rust side? (CXX crate)

Tags: c++, rust

Using the cxx crate: https://crates.io/crates/cxx

I have the following struct on Rust:

```
#[cxx::bridge]
pub(crate) mod ffi {
    enum SizeType {
        BYTE,
        WORD,
        DWORD,
        QWORD,
    }
     unsafe extern "C++" {
         //...
     }
}
```

which is also mapped on C++. How do I get `UniquePtr<SizeType>` on Rust? Do I have to write a C++ function to get it? If I do, there's no point in having the struct on the Rust side.

I tried

`let byte_ptr = UniquePtr::new(SizeType::BYTE);`

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
impl UniquePtr<SizeType> {}
```

See https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx/blob/a95eca61029b458998c1c5463481307af5643ba5/macro/src/expand.rs#L1408 and https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx/blob/a95eca61029b458998c1c5463481307af5643ba5/tests/ui/impl_trait_for_type.stderr.